# TypeError: Translate is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, google-translate

This is the code for transalting english to ru

```
'use strict';
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate');
const projectId = 'godwin-feb8f';
const translate = new Translate({
 projectId: projectId,
});
const text = 'Hello, world!';
const target = 'ru';
translate
.translate(text, target)
.then(results => {
const translation = results[0];
console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);
 })
.catch(err => {
console.error('ERROR:', err);
});
```

TypeError: Translate is not a constructor error occurs and if we declare it as function the error clears

but the next error appears for const declaration

Answer (score 7):

Try the .v2 version as below

```
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate');
```

results in `Translate` being undefined.

As [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/translate#using-the-client-library) states, `Translate` is `@google-cloud/translate` module exports:

```
const Translate = require('@google-cloud/translate');
```

Answer (score 0):

var Translate = require('@google-cloud/translate');

var translate = new Translate.Translate({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

Comment: Helped me mahipal! Thanks!